# Notification when certain posts are published

Tags: notifications

I normally work ahead of schedule and sometimes need to contact people when a certain post reaches publication. Is there any plugin that will do this?

It would need to be customisable for each post as most posts I don't need this reminder, and for the ones where I do need it I would need to write something different each time.

Comment: what's wrong with email?

Comment: Who needs to be notified and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider using a specific category or tag to use on posts that require notification?

If so, you could use [Peter's Collaboration E-mails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-collaboration-e-mails/) plugin which can automatically notify you (or other specific users) when a post is set to Pending, Scheduled, or Published.

In the plugin settings, you can define specific categories, post tags, authors, etc which defines certain notifications.

[image: Peter's Collaboration E-mails]

The settings shown above should alert me when any posts in the category Apple are submitted or published.

Comment: Dear Evan, sorry for the delay in answering I wanted to try it out first to make sure everything was working OK. I installed the plugins and set them up however the note never arrived. It appears on the dashboard, and the email came but without the note. It maybe a configuration problem, in any case it will suffice – the email reminds me to look at the dashboard where I find the note.

Comment: I also set up a new tag "NotifyMe", and installed the Hidden Tags plugin to hide it away from readers. This way it is easy to schedule notifications but without anyone else seeing it. Perhaps you could build this feature into a future version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [[CR]Post2HelloTXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cr-post2pingfm/) for this.

Add a twitter account and then add [Tweetymail](http://tweetymail.com/) notification to be notify when new twit arrived.